# symfony2 Argument 1 passed must implement interface Doctrine Collection, array given

Tags: forms, symfony, nested, arraycollection

I have a form that has 3 entites (Obras, FechaObra and HorarioObra) with one to many relationship. One Obra may have many FechaObra and one FechaObra may have many HorarioObra. but I made tha form as told in symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html but it gives me this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\ReservasBundle\Entity\FechaObra::setHorariosobra() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, array given, called in /var/www/html/grisar/entradas/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 410 and defined
```

I already defined horariosobra as an arraycollection, but it keeps giving me that error.

The source code of the bundle is in: [github.com/javiermarcon/tickets/tree/master/src/Acme/ReservasBundle](http://github.com/javiermarcon/tickets/tree/master/src/Acme/ReservasBundle)

Does anyone know why is giving me that error?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove strong typed `\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` from setter method:

```
public function setHorariosobra($horariosobra)
{
    // Be sure to "use" ArrayCollection class

    $this->horariosobra = new ArrayCollection($horariosobra);
    foreach ($horariosobra as $horarioobra) {
        $horarioobra->setObra($this);
    }
}
```

The should fix things. Remember, `Forms` component need not to know about `Doctrine` - it's entirely up to you to enforce usage of entities. Therefore, submitted data to setter method is generic array rather than `Doctrine`'s `Collection`